# $resource post json and retrieve json from/to mvc controller

Tags: c#, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc-5

This is my AngularJs code:

```
var adminApp = angular.module('adminApp', ['ngResource']);

adminApp.controller('adminCtrl', function ($scope, AdminService) {
    AdminService.getRoles().$promise.then(function (rolesData) {
        //roles data empty is coming eventhough mvc controller returns something
    });
});

$scope.saveUser = function () {
    var userData = { "email": $scope.useremail, "role": $scope.selectedRole.name };
    AdminService.postUser({user: userData}).$promise.then(function () {
    });
}
```

Service code

```
adminApp.factory('AdminService', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('', {}, {

        getRoles: {
            url: '/Admin/GetRoles',
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true
        },
        postUser:{
            url: '/Admin/PostUser',
            method:"Post",
            isArray: true,
           params: {user: '@userData'}
        },

    });

});
```

mvc code for post and get

```
public JsonResult GetRoles() {
    // data count is 2 here.that means some values there.
    return Json(data, JsonRequestbehavior.allowget);
}

public ActionResult PostUser(dynamic user)
{
    // user empty object coming here..
    return View();
}
```

Anyone provide me the right solution for posting Json to mvc controller and retrieving json from mvc action using `$resource` concept.

Comment: Can you output the result of `AdminService.getRoles()` to console (before the `$promise()`) to see what it returns?

Comment: @OzW how i can do that any idea?

Comment: `adminApp.controller('adminCtrl', function ($scope, AdminService) {
    var result = AdminService.getRoles();
    console.log(result);
});`

Comment: You can also look in the Network tab in Chrome Developer Tools to check if the request to '/Admin/GetRoles' is returning what you expect. Also, note that the `.then()` method accepts another argument which is the `errorCallback`. You can utilize that to check if the server is returning an error ([read more](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)).

Comment: @OzW i am getting the values rolesData but it is returning empty array like [0]=[] and [1]=[] when i use jsonresult in mvc. I have modified with content result then that time it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified MVC controller return type from Json to ContentResult. please find below code

```
public JsonResult GetRoles() {

     //data is string
    return new ContentResult{ Content= data, ContentType="application/json" };
}
```